# Use sed command to replace , appearing between numbers

Tags: unix, shell, script, sed

I have a CSV file where data are in the following format

```
|001|,|abc,def|,123456,789,|aaa|,|bbb|,444,555,666
```

I want to replace only those "," that appears between numbers with some other character like say SOH or $ or *

other "," appearing in the line should not get replaced i.e. to say I wish to have following output

```
|001|,|abc,def|,123456*789,|aaa|,|bbb|,444*555*666
```

Can someone please help me with sed command pattern to get the above desired output

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\),\(-\?[0-9]\)/\1\*\2/g'
```

The first section matches a digit followed by a comma followed by a digit or a -.  The next section simply regurgitates the first digit, the replacement character, and then the last digit.

This will catch any pattern like "#,#" or "#,-#", including some that may not be desired (e.g. "abc123,-def" --> "abc123*-def").  Fixing this requires more knowledge of the input stream.  (see the comments for details.)

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. It almost works !! BUT breaks when "," is followed by a Negative Number i.e. If data is \n |001|,|abc,def|,123456,789,|aaa|,|bbb|,444,555,-666,777  \n It converts to |001|,|abc,def|,123456*789,|aaa|,|bbb|,444*555,-666*777 Desired output is |001|,|abc,def|,123456*789,|aaa|,|bbb|,444*555*-666*777

Comment: I updated the answer to add handling of a minus sign on the second number.

Comment: @jwernemy As written, your pattern will also match `5,-hi!-`. The solution would be to replace the number pattern with a more general numeric pattern. Requiring that the number be delimited by `,` on both ends would also avoid capturing mixed alphanumeric entries like `,abc123,-45ok,`. The number pattern itself would be something like `\(\(-\|+\)?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*\)`; this handles sign-optional floating point representations, though not scientific-notation style numbers such as `1e5` or `3d7`.

Comment: @Jeremey - I see the issue of failing the case "123,-abc", so I will correct it.  The other cases you hint at are going to be a problem because we don't know how far backwards or forwards to look for a number because we don't know the field delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

Following seems to work :

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\),\([-0-9]\)/\1\*\2/g'
```